# Get all the urls from the internet related to a given keyword using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am learning scraping using BeautifulSoup. What I want to do is to get all available urls related to a keyword from the internet.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. Please read [ask]. Also, for starters, have a look at the [`BeautifulSoup` documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use requests python library to search on google.
Install requests by `pip install requests`
You can use google to search anything and parse the result with Beautifulsoup.
Following code search the `query` on google and after that BeautifulSoup is used to get the URLs that Google returned.

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = 'any search term'


r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q={}'.format(query))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    links.append(item.a['href'])

print(links)
```